# Extracting table from website using rvest in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, html-table, rvest

I am trying to extract this link "s3://sra-pub-src-5/SRR11393390/Run1_Plate3_S3_L004_R2_001.fastq.gz.1" in this address: "https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/index.html?view=run_browser&acc=SRR11393390&display=data-access". and I am using the `rvest` package in R but I am not sure how to extract information from that table.
This is my R code:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/index.html?view=run_browser&acc=SRR11393390&display=data-access"
html_content <- read_html(url)
html_content %>% html_nodes("body") %>% html_nodes("#ph-maincontent")
```

Please help

Comment: If you "view source" on that page, you can see that that link doesn't appear in the source code of that page. That path is likely inserted into the document after load via javascript.  It looks like you can get that data if instead you request the page https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra-db-be/run_new?acc=SRR11393390

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks you! I have a question, I tried to read that link as an xml file but I am getting an error ```"Error: XML content does not seem to be XML:",``` how can I read that info into R?

Comment: I'm not sure how you tried to read the file, but the `httr` package can read it: `httr::content(httr::GET("trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra-db-be/run_new?acc=SRR11393390"))`. It returns an XML document that you will have to navigate to extract the records you want.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you so much! you saved me lots of time. I was trying the "xml" package